# Escribir archivo en python error "argument must be str"

Tags: python-3.x, diccionarios, str

Tengo el siguiente duda, tengo un diccionario:

```
{'id': 3713454, 'ip': '10.10.20.202'}
{'id': 3713454, 'ip': '10.10.20.200'}
{'id': 3698684, 'ip': '10.10.20.253'}
```

Y deseo guardarlo en un archivo de texto localmente, pero cuando intento guardarlo me surge el siguiente error

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict
```

Intento que mi archivo se guarde y se vea de la siguiente manera, aplicando salto de línea y no se vea de largo como una línea.

Agradezco mucho por su tiempo en poder leer mi post y muchos saludos.

```
id: 3713454 ip: 10.10.20.202
id: 3713454 ip: 10.10.20.200
id: 3698684 ip: 10.10.20.253
```

Comment: La descripción de tu problema está bien, pero debieras incluir la parte relevante del código que estás utilizando en la pregunta. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderla. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo y bienvenido. No olvides hacer el [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`write()`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) acepta un solo argumento posicional, la cadena (`str`, `bytes`, ...) a escribir en el stream. No puedes pasarle directamente un diccionario tal como el error te muestra, debes generar la cadena de forma explícita a partir del mismo.

Por otro lado, ni `write` ni `writelines` agregan automáticamente el final de linea, por lo que también debes agregarlo explícitamente.

Teniendo ambas cosas en cuenta, debes hacer algo como:

```
file.write(f"id: {dic['id']} ip: {dic['ip']}\n")
```

---

```
datos = [
    {'id': 3713454, 'ip': '10.10.20.202'},
    {'id': 3713454, 'ip': '10.10.20.200'},
    {'id': 3698684, 'ip': '10.10.20.253'}
]

with open("datos.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for dic in datos:
        file.write(f"id: {dic['id']} ip: {dic['ip']}\n")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla, por su respuesta ya solucione mi duda y mi problema, gracias a su respuesta. ya entendí un poco mejor como es el proceso, si tuvieras algunos links de estudio sobre este tema en especifico te agradecería mucho o como debería buscarlo.